# Conditional cumulative sum in R dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to add a column to my df that will conditionally sum a column by group. When the value in the `margin` column is negative, it works fine. However, when that value is positive, I need to change the sum from addition to subtraction.

My df:

```
df <- data.frame(
  group = c('g1', 'g1', 'g1', 'g1', 'g1', 'g2', 'g2', 'g2', 'g2', 'g2', 'g2', 'g2', 'g2'),
  margin = c(-1.72, -1.13, -0.64, 1.75, 1.75, -7.22, -1.99, -1.13, -0.15, 1.31, 1.37, 1.98, 5.84) )
```

Output:

```
   group margin
1     g1  -1.72
2     g1  -1.13
3     g1  -0.64
4     g1   1.75
5     g1   1.75
6     g2  -7.22
7     g2  -1.99
8     g2  -1.13
9     g2  -0.15
10    g2   1.31
11    g2   1.37
12    g2   1.98
13    g2   5.84
```

Expected output:

```
df <- data.frame(
  group = c('g1', 'g1', 'g1', 'g1', 'g1', 'g2', 'g2', 'g2', 'g2', 'g2', 'g2', 'g2', 'g2'),
  margin = c(-1.72, -1.13, -0.64, 1.75, 1.75, -7.22, -1.99, -1.13, -0.15, 1.31, 1.37, 1.98, 5.84),
  exp_output = c(-1.72, -2.86, -3.50, -5.25, -7.00, -7.22, -9.22, -10.36, -10.51, -11.82, -13.20, -15.19, -21.03) )


   group margin exp_output
1     g1  -1.72      -1.72
2     g1  -1.13      -2.86
3     g1  -0.64      -3.50
4     g1   1.75      -5.25
5     g1   1.75      -7.00
6     g2  -7.22      -7.22
7     g2  -1.99      -9.22
8     g2  -1.13     -10.36
9     g2  -0.15     -10.51
10    g2   1.31     -11.82
11    g2   1.37     -13.20
12    g2   1.98     -15.19
13    g2   5.84     -21.03
```

So in line 2, you can see that the calculation is -1.72 (line 1 `margin` + line 2 `margin`) and so on when the `margin` value is negative. But when this changes in row 4 (1.75), it should be -3.50 (line 4) - 1.75.

How can this be achieved? I only know how to do the cumulative sum like so:

```
df <- df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(exp_output = cumsum(margin)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the cumulative sum of the negative absolute value:

```r
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(exp_output = cumsum(-abs(margin)))
#> # A tibble: 13 × 3
#> # Groups:   group [2]
#>    group margin exp_output
#>    <chr>  <dbl>      <dbl>
#>  1 g1     -1.72      -1.72
#>  2 g1     -1.13      -2.85
#>  3 g1     -0.64      -3.49
#>  4 g1      1.75      -5.24
#>  5 g1      1.75      -6.99
#>  6 g2     -7.22      -7.22
#>  7 g2     -1.99      -9.21
#>  8 g2     -1.13     -10.3 
#>  9 g2     -0.15     -10.5 
#> 10 g2      1.31     -11.8 
#> 11 g2      1.37     -13.2 
#> 12 g2      1.98     -15.2 
#> 13 g2      5.84     -21.0
```

Comment: don't forget to `ungroup()` :-)

Comment: I had a feeling I was over complicating things. Accepting this answer as it came in first.

Answer (score 3):

Because you're wanting to subtract the positive values, and add the positive values, it's the same as wanting to get the negative absolute value of the number. The most straightforward way of doing this with `dplyr` is:

```
dplyr::mutate(df, out = -cumsum(abs(margin)), .by = group)
```

Or with base R:

```
df <- transform(df, exp_output = ave(-abs(margin), group, FUN = cumsum))
```

Output:

```
   group margin    out
1     g1  -1.72  -1.72
2     g1  -1.13  -2.85
3     g1  -0.64  -3.49
4     g1   1.75  -5.24
5     g1   1.75  -6.99
6     g2  -7.22  -7.22
7     g2  -1.99  -9.21
8     g2  -1.13 -10.34
9     g2  -0.15 -10.49
10    g2   1.31 -11.80
11    g2   1.37 -13.17
12    g2   1.98 -15.15
13    g2   5.84 -20.99
```